# I have a header with a video background that looks good on a desktop but on a mobile it is pushed to the left side instead of full width

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a video background that looks good on a desktop but on a mobile it is pushed to the left side instead of full width.

I tried everything I can think of, but it is still not working as I would like.
It's about 2/3rds of the mobile view width starting on the left.
Interestingly, if I remove all the images, the header then works and spreads across to fill the full width as I want.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```css
.header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   display: block;  
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* This h1 is in case video doesn't work */
.header h1 {
   margin-top: 30px;
   color: #3F4EFF;
}
 
.example_container {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: ;
    justify-content: ; 
    width: 100%;    
    
}
.exampletext-container {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px; 
}

.exampletext-container pre {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
 
 .exampletext-container img {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 00px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
} 

.footer {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    display: block;
}

.footer p {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styletest.css" />
    <title>example</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #90ee903b">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="video6">
        <video
          autoplay
          muted
          defaultMuted
          playsinline
          src="images/touchblue4.mp4"
        ></video>
      </div>
    </div>

    <main>
      <div class="example_container">
        <div class="exampletext-container">
          <pre>
               couple of paragraphs
<img src="images/example.png">
              couple of paragraphs
<img src="images/example.png">
              couple of paragraphs
<img src="images/example.png">
              couple of paragraphs
<img src="images/example.png">
                </pre>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <p>A paragraph.</p>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without seeing relevant code we can have no proper idea of what is going on - and any answer will just be a guess. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.exampletext-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;

}


.video6{
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).